# Use phantomjs to fill a textfield, not working

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Trying to use phantomjs to do a query on a form that has a text field with name "category" and a button with value "search",  the following script will cause the button to be pressed, which triggered a POST message to be sent. However, in the POST message, I don't see the value for category.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.open('http://www.example.com', function() {
  page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
    page.evaluate(function() {
       $('input[name="category"]').value = "tmp1";
        console.log($('input[name="category"]').value);
        $('input[value="search"]').click();
    });
    //phantom.exit()
  });
});
```

If I do the following two lines on chrome browser developer console manually, the HTTP POST message sent does contain the right value for category field.  Any idea what went wrong?
Thanks.

```
$('input[name="category"]').value = "tmp1";
$('input[value="search"]').click();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.val()` to update the value of a form field with jQuery.

```
$('input[name="category"]').val("tmp1");
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, it gave me

$('input[name="category"]').val("tmp1");
TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'val'

Comment: When I use it instead of 
`$('input[name="category"]').value = "tmp1";`
wireshark monitoring showing there is no HTTP request sent. 
If I don't make the change, then it does the HTTP request, albeit without the category field.

Comment: @even, ignore my earlier comments.  Your solution works! I messed my URL. (didn't change the example.com back to my internal URL).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$('input[name="category"]')` returns a jQuery node list (like an array). So you need to select the first one to access the value attribute:

```
$('input[name="category"]')[0].value = "tmp1";
console.log($('input[name="category"]')[0].value);
```

The change is `[0]`.